# Как реализовать переход по страницам сайта без обрывания музыки? (Как у Vk)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, pjax, history-api

Мне нужно каким-то образом нужно сделать так, чтобы при переходе на другую страницу моего сайта, музыка, которая играет у пользователя не обрывалась, а продолжала играть.

Как пример - vk.

Какую технологию лучше использовать (AJAX + history API или PJAX) и как это реализовать на сайте?

Comment: а с чего ты взял, что в вк при обновлении страницы музыка продолжает играть? Нажми F5. Да и страница при переходах не меняется, а просто обновляется контент.

Comment: Уже убрал это из описания

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для этого нужно сделать Single Page Application.

Посмотри в сторону: Vue, Angular, React

Comment: Окей, допустим я взял React.js
И что в этом приложении нужно сделать (Какой алгоритм?)

Comment: почитай вот это: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5

Answer (score 1):

Есть вариант на главной странице сайта поместить плеер, а весь остальной сайт задать, как **src** для **iframe**, который будет во всю ширину и высоту окна:

```html
<audio id=audio src="sound.mp3"></audio>
<button onclick="audio.play()"> Включить фоновую музыку </button>
<button onclick="audio.pause()"> Выключить фоновую музыку </button>
<iframe src="https://site.ru" width=100% height=100%></iframe>
```

Этот вариант универсален, если понадобится озвучить фоновой музыкой чужой сайт. Правда, в этом случае разные сайты ведут себя по-разному - на одних, как и ожидается, можно свободно переходить по ссылкам и музыка не будет переставать играть, на других ссылки открываются во всю вкладку и музыка замолкает, а третьи сайты в iframe блокируются вообще.

Comment: С фреймами адресная строка браузера становится абсолютно бесполезной.